# Rospy not working even though it is imported?

Tags: rospy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My python script used to run but now does not work.  It does not give any errors but only returns a blank terminal.  It is also executable.  Below is a simplified version of the code with the output.  It seems the rospy functions are not working even though rospy is imported.  When I wrote the script as an individual script, it worked fine but as soon as I started messing with it so that it could be included in the launch file, it stopped working.  Any ideas?

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python
 import rospy
 import roslib

 print "test1"
 if __name__ == '__main__':
       print "test2"
       rospy.loginfo("test3")
       rospy.init_node('autodocking', anonymous=True)

OUTPUT:
test1
test2
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/229116/rospy-not-working-even-though-it-is-imported?/) by [pgigioli](https://answers.ros.org/users/26279/pgigioli/) on ROS Answers with karma: 354 on 2016-03-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The rospy.loginfo (and any other rospy function) ought to go after the init_node.

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2016-03-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pgigioli](https://answers.ros.org/users/26279/pgigioli/) on 2016-03-15**:
That solved the issue when I run the script individually but now when I run the script from a launch file or from rosrun, I get the error "from: can't read /var/mail/move_base_msgs.msg; from: can't read /var/mail/std_msgs.msg, etc." (basically all of the imports that I have) and nothing prints.